# Call of Duty MW3 Prestige token lost

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I just prestiged #2 and I received my prestige token. My extention cord was accidently pulled out and my system powered off. When I turned it back on and started up MW3, it told me I have 0 prestige tokens even though I hadn't spent the one I'd just acquired.

My console is a Playstation 3. I had prestiged two minutes prior to the cord being knocked out so it registered online that the token was in my possession. My PSN ID is `OnLyPros_xExCeLz`.

What can I do to get the token restored?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest contacting [Activision](http://activision.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/activision.cfg/php/enduser/home2.php) support.  They can probably take a look at your Call of Duty account and credit you the token if it was lost.

There's not much else you can do, as they control the system and the tokens.

Comment: thanks for the response, how do i go about contacting them? via email, phone etc?

Comment: [Call of Duty Website](http://www.callofduty.com/mw3) -> click on "Support" and write an E-Mail or open a topic in the [official Forum](http://www.callofduty.com/community/mw3/forums/call_of_duty_mw3/cod_mw3_playstation_3)

Comment: The word "Activision" in my answer has a link to the MW3 support site *right inside* like *magic*!

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted Activision support numerous times and they said they can't do anything about it.